# Android : openConnection() throws IOExeption ( Unable to find default handler for protocol: http )

Tags: java, android, jcifs

I have an android application that uses the jcifs library. Every time I try to openConnection() on an URL using HTTP protocol I get an IOExeption with the following message "Unable to find default handler for protocol: http". it works just fine with URLs using FTP protocol.

After some digging I suspect that the problem is from jcifs library.From the JCIFS documentation I found the following :

> The jCIFS NTLM support is implemented as a URLStreamHandler for HTTP connections. This handler "wraps" the default handler provided by your Java environment to add support for NTLM authentication.
>
> Add the "jcifs" package to the list of protocol handler packages. The "java.protocol.handler.pkgs" property is a pipe-separated ("|") list of packages which supply protocol handlers to Java.The "jcifs" package should be added to this list; this would typically be done by adding "-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=jcifs" to the command line when starting the application...
>
> [see full article](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/httpclient.html)

Can anyone help fix this problem.

Comment: I'm using Android 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
```

before you create your connection. This will install the jcifs package on your project.